# Prove or disprove if $µ_0(Bx, x) ≤ (Ax, x) ≤ µ_1(Bx, x), ∀x ∈ R^n$, then $κ(B^{−1}A) ≤ \frac{µ_1}{µ_0}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $A, B ∈ \mathbb{R}^{n×n}$ symmetric. Show that conditional number
$$κ(B^{−1}A) ≤ \frac{µ_1}{µ_0}$$
holds, if $B ∈ \mathbb{R}^{n×n}$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix satisfying
$$µ_0(Bx, x) ≤ (Ax, x) ≤ µ_1(Bx, x),  ∀x ∈ R^n$$
for some $0 < µ_0, µ_1 ∈ R$, $(\cdot,\cdot)$ is dot Euclidean product.

I have seen the proof of above statement in my lecture note. However, there is a mistake in the proof since they use the fact $κ(B^{−1}A) = \frac{\lambda_{\max}(B^{−1}A)}{\lambda_{\min}(B^{−1}A)}$. But its not correct because matrix $B^{−1}A$ is not symmetric. I was wonder is the above statement true or false. Can anyone give me a proof or a counter example? Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2):

Use the matrix $B^{-\frac12}AB^{-\frac12}$ instead of $B^{-1}$, where $B^{-\frac12}$ is the unique positive definite square root of the positive definite $B^{-1}$.

Note that if $B^{-1}Av=λv$, then also 
$$
B^{-\frac12}Av=λB^{\frac12}v \iff (B^{-\frac12}AB^{-\frac12})(B^{\frac12}v)=λ(B^{\frac12}v)
$$
so that the eigenvalues of both matrices are the same.

---

The claim as presented is slightly wrong, since the condition number in the 2-norm is the quotient of the largest and smallest singular values, not the eigenvalues. For SPD matrices these are equal, but not for other matrices.

To approach the problem, re-interpret the original inequalities as a statement about an elliptical norm 
$$
(x,y)_B=(B^{\frac12}x,B^{\frac12}y)_2
$$
Then changing variables to $y=B^{\frac12}x$, this inequality reads as
$$
µ_0\le\frac{(y, B^{-\frac12}AB^{-\frac12}y)_2}{(y,y)_2}\le µ_1
$$
which bounds the singular values of the symmetric $B^{-\frac12}AB^{-\frac12}$. Thus for the elliptical condition number related to the elliptical norm you get
$$
κ_B(A)
=κ_2(B^{-\frac12}AB^{-\frac12})
=\frac{σ_{\rm max}(B^{-\frac12}AB^{-\frac12})}{σ_{\rm min}(B^{-\frac12}AB^{-\frac12})}
=\frac{λ_{\rm max}(B^{-\frac12}AB^{-\frac12})}{λ_{\rm min}(B^{-\frac12}AB^{-\frac12})}
=\frac{λ_{\rm max}(B^{-1}A)}{λ_{\rm min}(B^{-1}A)}
\le\frac{µ_1}{µ_0}
$$

This should capture what was actually intended to be claimed about the condition number and thus the applications of it.

Comment: Hi @Lutzl If two matrix has the same eigenvalues. Does it imply that they have same conditional number?

Comment: See this link for the detail http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531161/condition-number-of-a-product-of-matrices

Comment: Yes, the condition number of $B^{-1}A$ is about the singular values of that matrix, which are the square roots of the eigenvalues of $B^{-1}A^2B^{-1}$ or $AB^{-2}A$.

Comment: Hi @Lutzl what is condition number of $B^{-1}A$?

Comment: That is the question. The quoted text assumes the max. quotient of eigenvalues, but in general $κ(M)=\|M\|·\|M^{-1}\|=σ_{max}(M)/σ_{min}(M) = \sqrt{λ_{max}(M^*M)/λ_{min}(M^*M)}$.